# Little help with prediction

Tags: r, prediction

I have energy consumption data from a device for the past two weeks.

I have to predict energy consumption of this device for another week.

I am not sure how to forecast this.

Does anybody know how to do that?

If there a way to do that in R? I've just started learn the R language.

Comment: Why not start in Excel?  Once you know what you want to do in Excel and how you want to do it, then you can move to R.  If this is a one-off problem that you're doing out of interest, R is (in my opinion) a bit too steep of a learning curve.  In any event, forecasting is about how, not the package.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't agree with the advice to "start in Excel." I say, force yourself through the learning curve while you have motivation and time, so that you already can do it easily when those things are lacking.

Comment: The simplest prediction is that it will be exactly the same next week. Any other prediction requires assumptions, which you haven't stated...

Comment: @Harvey - "exactly the same next week" also involves assumptions; assumptions of some kind are inescapable. $\quad$ Kacu - Before you consider R, you need to consider what problem you're actually solving (in explicit terms, not merely 'predict energy consumption') -- you need some kind of model/assumptions. You can't just predict out of thin air, you need to know, infer - or at least assume - something about what is going on. When you say you have energy consumption for two weeks, is this weekly consumption? Daily consumption? Hourly consumption? What other information/context do you have?

Comment: I have daily energy consumption from past two weeks and I have to predict for another week. After that I have to make a plot in R with what I predict in that week (from Monday -> Sunday). Assume the same consumption is not good for me. I need something that predict data would be a little different from past data.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the model you have in mind. For basic exponential smoothing, there's an excellent write-up [here](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html#forecasts-using-exponential-smoothing) that is easy to read and has lots of code demos. It's part of an e-book on using R to analyze time series for people with minimal R and programming experience.

Comment: (+1) Fair enough.  I see from the reference you've given that yes, perhaps it is actually not too hard anymore for even a casual user to step into R and do things right.  Thanks for challenging.

Comment: +1 There's also [this excellent book on forecasting](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/), which also uses R.